# 90s B-rated horror movie with a haunted house

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching a movie when I was around 6-8 (1990 - 1992) in Brazil, what makes the film has benn released probably around 3 years before at least.
In this movie there was this house that was haunted by some kind of witch/spirit/demon or something. I remember the title in portuguese having the word "bruxa" (wicth in Portuguese), so I will call this thing witch.

I remember a few scenes of this movie:

- A family moves to this house and the house was next to a cliff with the sea on the cliff.
- There was a man wearing a crucifix and he was proud of his "protection." After being captured he is crucified and then fired at the cross.
- There was an old woman, who was tied to a chair and had her lips pierced by two people who looked like cavemen by their clothes and hair. Then she was burned in the fireplace.
- There was girl called Jane around her 16's or 18's who gives a little boy called Tommy (that was maybe her sibling or cousin) a toy recorder as a gift.
  In this scene the Jane demonstrates to Tommy how the toy works and she records the phrase: "Jane loves Tommy".
  After she leaves, Tommy records several times the phrase: "I love you Jane".
- In the end of the movie, the above mentioned recording is what defeats the witch, in a scene where
  the witch attacks Tommy and he drops the voice recorder, wich makes it starts playing the "I love you Jane" phrase
  repeatedly. This makes the witch insane and she suicides jumping through a window in the house and falling on the cliff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Witchery*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096453/) (1988)? The Brazilian title was *Bruxa: Encontros Diabólicos*.

From Wikipedia:

> Gary (David Hasselhoff) and his gal pal Leslie (Leslie Cumming) visit an island off the coast of Massachusetts where a haunted resort hotel looms to do research on witchcraft. They are joined by the Brooks family (including a pregnant Linda Blair), prospective buyers of the property. When a storm prevents them from leaving the island, they are subjected to the wrath of an evil witch who will not quit until all of them die.

The film features characters called Jane and Tommy Brooks.

---

Found with the Google query `filme bruxa jane tommy` (`movie witch jane tommy`).  One of the results is [this review](https://bocadoinferno.com.br/criticas/2015/03/bruxa-encontros-diabolicos-1988/) (in Portuguese).

Comment: Thank you @Jenayah, the movie is exactly this.

Comment: @Diego glad to help! If this helped you, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark under the voting buttons on your left. Since Valorum posted the same answer, feel free to decide which one was the most helpful to you :)

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Witchery](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096453/) (also known as La Casa 4)?

[This review](https://www.braineater.com/house/casa4.html) mentions the line you've referred to

> Before the boat sails for the island, little Tommy meets a young girl in a wheelchair. When the girl finds out that Tommy is going to the island, she tells him that a witch used to live there. Apparently this tale is common around the town, since the local sailors are reluctant to take the family out. Eventually a boat is hired, and on the journey out Jane takes the opportunity to give Tommy the tape recorder she bought earlier. She shows him how to use it, recording the phrase **"Jane loves Tommy very much"**, and playing it back for him. Tommy goes off to play with the recorder, testing it by taping **"I love you, Jane"** over and over again.